# Speaker Amplifier for First Alert Keypad

Tags: amplifier

I have gone back to the drawing board and rebuilt this for simplicity. The problem I have now is the if I use the Keypad Buss 12VDC power I get oscillation. It will not oscillate if I use a separate power source, but the only option I have for power is the keypad buss.[image]

Comment: Have you measured the output voltage from the 12V to 9V converter?

Comment: My guess is you have something connected backwards - maybe the speaker + is going to line in - and speaker - to line in +. Wouldn't matter with a battery, but would play merry hell with a PSU.

Comment: Thanks for your reply's. I have simplified it a bit, but still get ocillation after 30-45 secs of being powered up using the KP Buss as the power source.

Answer (score 1):

It's no big surprise your circuit is oscillating since you haven't bypassed the amp at all.  At the very least, put a 10 µF ceramic cap as close as possible across the power leads of the amplifier IC.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to put a 100 µF or more electrolytic across the 12 V where it enters your board.

The reason you are seeing oscillation is because the power supply has way too much impedance at the oscillating frequency, and certainly other freuquencies.  Generally you can't count on reasonable AC impedance of a power supply coming from elsewhere via some wires.  Fix that with local capacitors.